# Zend cache doesn't kick in

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

Ok, here's the problem:

```
$frontendOptions = array(
  'lifetime' => 7200,
  'debug_header' => true, // for debugging, but it doesn't work...
  'regexps' => array(

         // Cache the static pages
         '^/pages/' => array('cache' => true),
     )
  );

$backendOptions = $config->cache->backOptions->toArray();

// getting a Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page object
require_once 'Zend/Cache.php';
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page',
  $config->cache->backend,
  $frontendOptions,
  $backendOptions);

$cache->start();
```

This doesn't do anything at all. Page loading times are exactly the same and the folder indicated in `$backendOptions` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

By the way: `$config->cache->backend` reads `"file"`.

Comment: Are you calling it directly on the bootfile or index.php file?

Comment: what exactly is /pages/? do you have a "pageController()"? You can try '^/$' as regex to test if there is a problem with matching the path. 

Any Warnings/Errors/Notices in the errorlogs?

Did you make sure that php has write-access to the cachedirectory?

And the last thing i can think of right now: try 'File' with an uppercase 'F' as Backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, following my tradition of answering my own questions, here comes the answer, and a subquestion, if anyone knows what's going on:

Basically, this thing doesn't work out of the box if you happen to run something more advanced than Hello World. I had a cookie set and since it found a cookie, it refused to do anything about it, so one hour digging in the caching code I discovered that the magic needed was simply to set

```
'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
```

And well, since all cookies are more or less unique and I don't really want to care about them, I set

```
'make_id_with_cookie_variables' => false
```

So now it works flawlessly.

Thanks to Chris and smoove for taking the time out and now in hindsight your comments made a lot of sense. Naturally though, I didn't have any errors or warnings and "File" was indeed spelled with uppercase.

What I wonder now is if I can send a spike to delete the proper cache file upon certain circumstances. I can hammer it (copy the ID generator in the cache and unset() the proper target), but there might be a fancier solution. If you have any idea, let me know.

Comment: your answer is valuable for the approach

http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/381-Zend-Framework-Page-Caching-Part-2-Controller-Based-Cache-Management.html

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **config/application.ini** and set:

```
resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
```

Answer (score 0):

***If you are done with config/application.ini , just copy and past the code below and have fun. 
Please do remember the temporary file ; I have used here servercache you can use temp or tmp or whatsoever.***

```
$frontendOptions = array(
        'lifetime' => 900,
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'default_options' => array(
            'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_files_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_get_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_post_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_session_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_files_variables' => true,
            'make_id_with_cookie_variables' => true,
            'cache'=>true
        ),


    );

    $backendOptions = array(
        'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/servercache/'
    );
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
    $cache->start();
```